# How to check per XSD that content between tags exists

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

for my ".xsd file"  I'm  searching for a possibility to check(only for some tags) if a content between these is present.

E.g.:

```
<sometag> some content</sometag> # => valid

<sometag></sometag> # => not valid
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and very simple. You just have to restrict the element minimum length by setting *minLength* restriction to 1. Example:

```
<xs:element name="sometag">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

If you're using XSD 1.1 you could also do it using assertions (e.g.:`<xsd:assert test="/sometag != ''"/>`.  )